# Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot issue when swapping with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, swap

I try to perform a swap between 2 Azure slots (Staging and Production) on a QA environment. For that I use PowerShell and use Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot cmdlet.
Below what I execute:
*`

> Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name "http://qa-2.cloudapp.net/" -Slot1
>   "Production" -Slot2 "Staging" -Force -Verbose -Debug

`*

But I got the following error:

> Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot : The website must have at least two slots to
>   apply swap At
>   C:\PrivateAgents\agent2_work\r6\a\MyCompany-CI-Template\drop#1129\mycompany-swapslots-azure.ps1:222
>   char:2
>   +     Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name "http://qa-2.cloudapp.net/" -Slot1 ...
>   +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.SwitchAzureWebsiteSlotCommand
>
> DEBUG: AzureQoSEvent: CommandName - Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot; IsSuccess
>   - False; Duration - 00:01:02.5624486; Exception - System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: The website
>   must have at least two slots to apply swap    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.SwitchAzureWebsiteSlotCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord();

I use Debug mode to have more details but I don't understand what does it mean. I am a newbie in Azure and Powershell as well.

I made sure the right AzureSubscription is set as current one before to execute my cmdlet.

Anyone got the same issue as me before?

I have a doubt about the "-Name" value I used. I use site URL I found on the Azure portal. I don't know if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of your websites in the subscription use the below PowerShell cmdlet:

**Get-AzureWebsite**

**Note:** The website should be something like this "**constosoweb**" and azure website looks like **contosoweb.cloudapp.net**.

For more details, you may refer "[Swap Slots in Azure Web Site when there are 2 or more staging slots using Azure PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/harikharan/2015/01/01/swap-slots-in-azure-web-site-when-there-are-2-or-more-staging-slots-using-azure-powershell/)".

Answer (score 0):

> I have a doubt about the "-Name" value I used. I use site URL I found
>   on the Azure portal. I don't know if it is correct.

`-Name` is **the name of the website**, we can use ARM powershell to get it:

`Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroupname> -Name <webappname>`

Like this:

[image]

> Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot : The website must have at least two slots

According to this error message, we should **add at least two slots** to that website:

[image]

Then we can run `Switch-AzureWebsiteSlot -Name jasonapp3 -Slot1 jasonapp32 -Slot2 jasonapp4`, here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Pradeep and Jason,

Thanks a lot for your help.
Thanks to your advices I figured out where was my issue. In fact we use Azure Cloud Service and not WebSite. That's why my cmdet failed.

I looked for cmdlet suit to Cloud Service and I found `Move-AzureDeployment` that works perfectly for me.

Thanks